# Python REST API Data Extraction with requests library

Tags: python, pandas, api, rest, python-requests

Is there a better way to write this piece of code to extract data from a REST API with the requests library? It currently takes about 10 minutes to finish extracting the data from the REST API. I think the code below may not be the most efficient method.

````
import time
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def loan_rest_api():
    '''
    This function calls the rest api and stored the data in a pandas dataframe.
    '''

    
    search_start = time.time()
    print("Extracting loan data from Rest API...")

    # Declaring variables for the first page number and the list that contains the results for each page in the REST API.
    num = 1
    pages = []

    # Declaring variable to look up the correct table in the REST API.
    table = 'loan'

    # The 'loan' table has about 50 columns, but these are the ones I need.
    # Declaring columns variable to choose the columns I'm interested in.
    columns = '''    
                loan_id,
                loan_name,
                loan_parent_id,
                loan_status,
                loan_type,
                loan_classification,
                loan_create_date,
                loan_last_update,
                loan_amount,
                loan_amount_last_update,
                loan_balance,
                loan_balance_last_update,
                loan_interest,
                loan_interest_last_update,
                city,
                office_location,
                project_name          
            '''

    # Infinitely loop needed to iterate through all of the pages of data that the loan
    # table contains. Since I don't know how many pages there are, I loop
    # through the entire table until it reaches the end. Once
    # it reaches the end, the While True condition no longer holds so the loop stops.
    while True:

        # Since the loan table in the rest api contains several pages, I had to implement a 
        # pagination functionality to prevent the function from either timing out or crashing.
        pagination = {'pageSize': '5000',
                      'pageNumber': str(num),
                      'attributes': columns.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')}

        # Send a GET request to the REST API on the corresponding loan table.
        # the params parameter contains the pagination requirements. Start 
        # with page 1, then page 2, etc. For each resulting data pull, append
        # the page to the pages list.
        # num increase by 1 on the next loop until it reaches the end.
        response = requests.get(REST_API_LINK + table, params=pagination)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            break
        results = response.json()
        pages.append(pd.DataFrame(results))
        num += 1

    # Create a pandas dataframe. This contains about 200,000 rows and it's
    # 40MB in size when exported as a csv file.
    final_df = pd.concat(pages, ignore_index=True)

    # Right now this takes about 800 seconds.
    search_end = time.time()
    print(f" ...search completed in {search_end - search_start: .2f} seconds.")

    return print('Search Done.')


```
````

Comment: Yes, I'm on it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi @Peilonrayz , I included descriptions on the code. I can elaborate on specific areas if needed.

Comment: Seems the most time consumed action here is downloading the json data from server. To speed up, maybe you can download multiple parts concurrency, and or increase pageSize (if the server not configured to limit request frequency).

Comment: Hi @tsh , I increased the pageSize from 5000 to 8000 and the extraction time improved by 6.5% going from 800 seconds to 750 seconds. At least it's something! I'll keep tinkering with the pagination parameter. All other tables in the REST API take about 1, 2, or 3 seconds. It's this Loan table with several pages of JSON data that take a while to extract.

Comment: pageSize is now 15000 and time decreased to 600 seconds! Thank you @tsh!

Comment: pageSize is now at 20000 and time is still at 600 seconds. Further increase in page size have no effect. Will leave it there for now, and I'll continue to read some other REST API python examples to see how others have written and optimized theirs. Thank you!